# dropzone.js not moving file to upload folder

Tags: php, jquery, upload, dropzone.js

i work with the dropzone.js, `upload` plugin and `PHP`. I am trying to use `dropzone` show success Icon and print image preview, but it is not uploading my images to the upload directory. how can I fix this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
  <form action="<?PHP echo SITE.'/controller/'?>upload.php"></form>
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element
    // The configuration we've talked about above
    url: '<?PHP echo SITE.'/controller/'?>upload.php',
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 100
  }

 });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = '../../uploads/news/';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

}
?>
```

Comment: what about your server-side code? Done any basic debugging there? You're also missing the `enctype` attribute on your form, so unless the dropzone plugin adds that, you'll NEVER be able to upload a file.

Comment: you right! see new Updated my question!

Comment: you have NO error handling at all. at bare minimum you should have something like `if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { die("upload failed with error #" . $_FILES['file']['error']); }`, which will give you at least a clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: Your upload handler is also a MAJOR security vulnerability. You blindly use the user-provided filename, which allows a malicious user to scribble a file of their choosing ANYWHERE on your server.

Comment: are you working locally?  if so... it's ok for now to use no validation just to get your code working in a "ideal state" but I also strongly recommend you follow @MarcB advice if this is anywhere exposed.  I have some very simple php code I can share as an answer, along with the client side, so you will see what I mean

Comment: this php file is simple! if you have any idea for better code please write answer with new and worked code for my question. Thanks

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch: yes i working local server(xampp).

Comment: good man! woman? I know... hacker!

Comment: I see you have `/controller/` in your forms action. Are you using a specific PHP framework?  I happen to have a Zend Framework implementation of dropzone that you could see if I can get your GH username.

Comment: @MarcB, I gave him a few security tips for both client and server in my answer...

Comment: `chmod 777 uploads` in parent directory

read http://stackoverflow.com/a/30607096/4035702

Answer (score 7):

**There are 2 different things needed to fix this problem.**

Looks to me like you are using http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php to get started with dropzone. Depending on you OS, you WILL need to alter your file permissions, even though the comment thread on that page says it works locally.  That is not true for all AMP stacks or even in different stack versions/distributions.

**First**

Make sure the permissions of your upload path are set properlly.  Certain folders (the `tmp` psuedo folder for instance, don't have this problem, but user created endpoints may.  If you update your question with your specific OS/stack name, I'll update this answer with the specific steps necessary to do so.

**Second**

Add `enctype= multipart/form-data` attribute to your form tag.

#### Very Important

On the subject brought up by [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b), I'd like to point out that this tutorial is just a starting point, and **should not** be uploaded to any publicly accessible environment without some sort of validation and security.  Basic security for this would be things like, only allowing certain extensions to be uploaded (can be done server side, and also configured in dropzone.js initialization), and adding a [CSRF token](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries).  Below is some recommended dropzone options configuration settings to at least strengthen the validation on the client side:

```
var unique = "some-unique-string";
var acceptedFileTypes = "image/*"; //dropzone requires this param be a comma separated list

Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { 

  // your other settings as listed above
  maxFiles: 10, // allowing any more than this will stress a basic php/mysql stack
  paramName: unique,
  headers: {"MyAppname-Service-Type": "Dropzone"},
  acceptedFiles: acceptedFileTypes

}
```

And some PHP things to note based on the above:

- you will need to add a check to ensure the custom header is in the request (this is just one more easy security step
- Add a check with php to ensure the files have an acceptable type (you always should do this regardless of the server side validation)
- I recommend you convert all file names to lowercase before validating them with php
- **EDIT:** you will also need to make sure to change your php `$_FILES['file']` to instead match the unique string configured by the dropzone `paramName` option.. `&_Files['some-unique-string']`

Comment: good stuff. I've already read this article. I change my code for your example but not work for me! can you test your code in runnable? Thanks

Comment: as I mentioned... I need to know information about your stack and OS so I can specify how you update permissions.  I bet if you check your apache error log, you'll see permission errors every time you send a file to your `upload.php` script.  If that is the case then I **guarantee** the method described in my answer is how to correct your problem.

Comment: “maxFiles: 10, // allowing any more than this will stress a basic php/mysql stack” Not if you set `parallelUploads: 1`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and i gave wirte permission for the files and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

use this upload.php it is working:

---

```
<?php
$upload_dir = 'uploads';
if (!empty($_FILES)) 
{ 
     $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];//this is temporary server location

     // using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant is a good practice, it makes your code portable.
     $uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $upload_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

     // Adding timestamp with image's name so that files with same name can be uploaded easily.
     $mainFile = $uploadPath.time().'-'. $_FILES['file']['name'];

     move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$mainFile);
}

?>
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to mention how this fixes the problem